# Obtain multiple user inputs from mobile apps that run code like SoloLearn?

Tags: android, python, mobile, input, user-input

I have a program of tic tac toe in Python that I wish to post on SoloLearn, which is a mobile application that runs code in different languages (i.e. Java, C++, Python, etc.) 
However, even though my program requires multiple inputs, from hopefully two users, it ends after the first input.
The prompt used is what I see too often on these type of apps, It states that the program requires input but you must enter all of the input somehow all at once.
Is there any way to obtain multiple user inputs from mobile apps that run such code.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the string `split()` method for this. Again, you have a few options.

- Option 1 (standard): assign `input().split()` to a variable, and access
  the inputs by index.
- Option 2 (keeps all but special characters): assign `input().split()`
  to a variable; filter them with the `isalnum()` method.
- Option 3 (only keeps letters): assign `input().split()` to a variable;
  clean them up using the `isalpha()` method.
- Option 4 (only keeps digits): assign `input().split()` to a variable;
  filter them with the string `isnumeric()` method.

Here's an instance of **Option 1**:

```
query = input().split()
var1 = query[0]
var2 = query[1]
```

For the input "a1, b2", var1, var2 = "a1,", "b2".

Use **Option 2** to remove those ugly commas:

```
query = input().split()
for index, number in enumerate(query):
    query[index] = ''.join(c for c in number if c.isalnum())
var1 = query[0]
var2 = query[1]
```

For the input "a1, b2", var1, var2 = "a1", "b2".

An instance of **Option 3**:

```
query = input().split()
for index, number in enumerate(query):
    query[index] = ''.join(c for c in number if c.isalpha())
var1 = query[0]
var2 = query[1]
```

For the input "a1, b2", var1, var2 = "a", "b".

For numeric-string inputs, use **Option 4** like this:

```
query = input().split()
for index, number in enumerate(query):
    query[index] = ''.join(c for c in number if c.isalpha())
var1 = query[0]
var2 = query[1]
```

For the input "a1, b2", var1, var2 = "1", "2".

Answer (score 0):

the sololearn playground allows multiple inputs

enter each input on a new line in the input prompt
infinite loop works not though